# How to generate randomized pairs of elements in php without duplicates?

Tags: php, arrays, random

I'm trying to generate randomized pairs of elements:

```
<? 
$myarray1=array('1','2','3'); 
$myarray2=array('a','b','c'); 

$key_rand = array_rand($myarray1);

echo '<p>'.$myarray1[$key_rand].'</p>'; 
echo '<p>'.$myarray2[$key_rand].'</p>'; 


$myarray1=array('1','2','3'); 
$myarray2=array('a','b','c'); 

$key_rand = array_rand($myarray1);

echo '<p>'.$myarray1[$key_rand].'</p>'; 
echo '<p>'.$myarray2[$key_rand].'</p>'; 


$myarray1=array('1','2','3'); 
$myarray2=array('a','b','c'); 

$key_rand = array_rand($myarray1);

echo '<p>'.$myarray1[$key_rand].'</p>'; 
echo '<p>'.$myarray2[$key_rand].'</p>'; 
?>
```

as a result I sometimes get duplicated pairs, which I don't want - for example:

2b
2b
3c

or

1a
1a
1a

I want to get only unique pairs each time, for example:

2b
1a
3c

or

1a
3c
2b

etc.

I'm probably doing it wrong, how do I fix that? Sorry new to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$myarray1=array('1','2','3'); 
$myarray2=array('a','b','c'); 

$cnt=0;
$final = array();

while( $cnt<3 ) {
    $key_rand = array_rand($myarray1);
    $temp_arr = $myarray1[$key_rand].$myarray2[$key_rand];
    if( !in_array($temp_arr,$final) ) {
        $final[] = $temp_arr;
        $cnt++;
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($final);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3c
    [1] => 1a
    [2] => 2b
)
```

generate random pairs with while and push into an array and check if exists with `in_array` to be uniq

if you have an array with 2 elements and `$cnt>2` ... will be an infinite loop

> Late added by @benua "great, but I need to insert the output into html like that: c a b is it possible?"

```
$myarray1=array('1','2','3'); 
$myarray2=array('a','b','c'); 

$cnt=0;
$final = array();

while( $cnt<3 ) {
    $key_rand = array_rand($myarray1);
    if( !in_array($key_rand,$final) ) {
        $final[] = $key_rand;
        $cnt++;
    }
}

$links = array();
foreach( $final as $key ) {
    $links[] = "<a href='".$myarray1[$key]."'>".$myarray2[$key]."</a>";
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($links);


<pre>Array
(
    [0] => <a href='1'>a</a>
    [1] => <a href='3'>c</a>
    [2] => <a href='2'>b</a>
)
```

Comment: great, but I need to insert the output into html like that:

<a href="3">c</a>
<a href="1">a</a>
<a href="2">b</a>

is it possible?

Comment: i have edited. but explain from beginning what you need to do... not by steps

Comment: sorry:) I will next time

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't really want random pairs but instead you want to order your array randomly. You can use [`array_shuffle`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) for that.

So what I would do, is generate a final array with the elements you want (no need for 2 arrays if you always combine the same elements) and do an `array_shuffle()` on that.

Answer (score 0):

I would build an array with all the posibilities first of all.

Then you can extract random items of that array, so the would never be repeated.

```
<?php

$myArray1=array('1','2','3'); 
$myArray2=array('a','b','c');

$myBigArray = array();

foreach($myArray1 as $array1Item){
  foreach($myArray2 as $array2Item){
    $myBigArray[] = $array1Item . $array2Item;
  }
}

// Now $myBigArray has [1a, 1b, 1c, 2a, 2b, 2c, 3a, 3b, 3c]

$randomPosition = rand(0, count($myBigArray)-1);
$randomPair = array_slice($myBigArray, $randomPosition, 1);
echo '<p>'.randomPair.'</p>';

// Note that array_slice actually modifies the input array

$randomPosition = rand(0, count($myBigArray)-1);
$randomPair = array_slice($myBigArray, $randomPosition, 1);
echo '<p>'.randomPair.'</p>';
```

We could make this code much more efficient, but this will do the trick the easy way.